# My TAB fragment does not refresh until i restart my application or switch to my 3rd TAB

Tags: android, android-tablayout

My application consists of 3 tabs,and from the first tab I am using a button to go to a new activity. On my new activity I am saving data to SQLite DATABASE. and when I return back to the Tab it does not get refreshed automatically. To bring the data on Tab I have to either restart the app or when I move to 3rd tab by which 1 tab is destroyed and recreated when I return back to 2nd Tab.
So how to refresh the tab or Activity which contains the Tab.
My codes for Tabs are:

```
    public class MedListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.med_list_activity);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new PrescriptionFragment(), "Prescriptions");
        adapter.addFragment(new AccountSettingFragment(), "Accounts");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

and my Tab fragment where I am starting the new Activity.

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    //       TextView timeText= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
    //        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
           // timeText.setText(currentDateTimeString);
            FloatingActionButton addBtn=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent newActivity;
                    newActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), AddMedication.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(newActivity);

                }
            });
recyclerViewPassed=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.PastMedList);
        recyclerViewup=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.UpMedList);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerViewPassed.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerViewup.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager2);
        context=getActivity();
        databaseAdaptor=new DatabaseAdaptor(context);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        switch (day) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                daysName="Sun";
                break;

            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                daysName="Mon";
                break;

            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                daysName="Tue";
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                daysName="Wed";
                break;

            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                daysName="Thu";
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                daysName="Fri";
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                daysName="Sat";
                break;
        }
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapterpassed();
        initializeAdapterup();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
           }



    private void initializeData() {
       databaseAdaptor.checkDaysName(daysName);
    }
    private void initializeAdapterpassed(){
        RVApassedAdapter adapter = new RVApassedAdapter(databaseAdaptor.passedLists);
       recyclerViewPassed.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void initializeAdapterup(){
        RvUpAdapter adapter = new RvUpAdapter(databaseAdaptor.upList);
        recyclerViewup.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

How do i Refresh my Tab Activity automatically after I save my data in DB .

Comment: Set a flag on your `AddMedication` Activity like `public static boolean isDataEntered = false;` and set this flag to `true` when you insert data into database. and then in `onResume()` of your fragment check `if(AddMedication.isDataEntered) { 
AddMedication.isDataEntered = false;
initializeData();
        initializeAdapterpassed();
        initializeAdapterup(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MedListActivity, add the below code:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    if(viewPager != null && viewPager.getAdapter() != null) {
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It should refresh the tabs.

If this is not working, do the below:

1. Move the Adapter creation mechanism (I assume this is the data you want to display) to a separate method, which will be called in OnCreate. This will not change current behavior.
2. **In the Fragment**, override the onResume method and also call this new adapter-creating method.

---

Summing up our comments discussion, the final solution is adding the following method to the Fragment code:

```
@Override 
public void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    // Here we call the data setup methods again, to reflect 
    // the changes which took place then the Fragment was paused
    initializeData(); 
    initializeAdapterpassed(); 
    initializeAdapterup(); 
}
```

Comment: And where is the code which should set the value to the View?

Comment: I added a deeper solution, but just to make sure - did you annotate the first solution as @Override?

Comment: yes 
`@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            if(viewPager != null && viewPager.getAdapter() != null) {
                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


    }`

Comment: Can we do like destroying the tab and recreating it on when resumed.

Comment: Can we do like destroying the tab and recreating it on when resumed.
Which is similar to the Tab functionality which is: it keeps the previous and next tab in memory. so out of 3 when i move to 2nd Tab it keeps the 1st tab on hold and loads the 3rd. when move to 3rd it removes the 1st tab and when again moved to 1st it loads the tab so in this way data gets refreshed. Is there any way to do similar to this when when a new activity is triggered ,tab should be destroyed and reloaded when returned back to it.

Comment: We could, but we shouldn't really :-) Just invoke the data setting method inside the Fragment, in the onResume method and it should work nice and smooth :)

Comment: you can edit your answer as i have used it inside my HomeTab
`@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapterpassed();
        initializeAdapterup();

    }`

Comment: I am glad you did :) Fragment Pagers are tricky, as they can not be treated as normal Adapter views - each fragment holds its own state and should be asked directly :)